# What is the image of a unit circle under the map $f(z)=1+z^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

> The image of a unit circle under the map $f(z)=1+z^2$ is :
>
> 1. again the same unit circle
> 2. another circle with different centre but same radius
> 3. another circle with same centre but different radius
> 4. not a circle
> 5. None of the above

My Try:   Consider the unit circle $|z|=1$.  If we write this as $ \left\{ e^{i\theta} : 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \right\} $, then, its image under $z \mapsto {1+z^2} $ is readily seen to be
$$
\{ 1+e^{2i \theta}=2 (\cos \theta )e^{i \theta} : \theta \in [0,2\pi]\} 
$$

(Using $e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} = 2\cos(\theta)$)

Now, I am not sure how to progress further. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Break it up into two mappings.  First, you have $z^2$. $re^{i\theta} \rightarrow r^2e^{2i\theta}$. Then you have $z+1$, which is a translation by 1.

Comment: The image of the unit circle *centred at the origin* is a circle, but the image of an *arbitrary* unit circle may not be.

Comment: For example, here is a plot of the images of unit circles centered at $0,\frac12,1,\frac32,2$: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nOYFN.png

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rahul. Can you help me find out how I can learn plotting those images (by providing important links from where I can actually learn) as there are many cases where I have to draw geometrical figure but I could not do so because of ignorance ....

Comment: Well, I can tell you how I plotted *these* figures, but it sounds like you want an entire tutorial on how to plot arbitrary geometrical figures and curves -- and that's too long for a comment and I won't have time to write a full answer. If you know Python you can try [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). For Euclidean geometry try [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/). I made the plot in Mathematica, but that's not free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$z^2$ maps the unit circle onto itself.  It actually maps the upper unit semicircle onto the whole unit circle and does the same with the lower unit semicircle.  Then +1 shifts it to the right. So you get the circle $|z-1| = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Paul said, we have that $(e^{i\theta})^2=e^{i2\theta}$, with modulus 1, i.e., a point in the unit circle centered at the origin. Then we translate by $1$, to get the image set {$1+e^{i2\theta} $}. And every point is hit, i.e., the map is a bijection of $S^1$ to itself; $e^{i\theta_0}=e^{2(i\theta_0/2)}$. You can see the map is also an injection.